# laggy Shiny uiOutput

Tags: r, shiny

One of my apps is displaying a ggplot via `uiOutput('plot.ui')` and plot.ui is rendered through `renderUI()`.

```
  output$plot.ui=renderUI({
   plotOutput('plot', width=a function(), height=a function())
   })
```

The code works, but it is very laggy. It seems that this is a two-step process. In my app, it first renders 'plot' (which is a ggplot rendered by renderPlot), then it resizes the plot according the specified width and height. The lag between the two steps is significant (about 3 seconds). I checked it by wrapping a withProgress() around plotOutput(), and the problem still exists. I am wondering why this problem exists and if there is any way to solve it.

A small example is attached to illustrate this problem.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui=shinyUI(
    pageWithSidebar(
      titlePanel('test'),
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput('width','Width: ', min=0,max=1000,value=100),
        sliderInput('height','Height: ',  min=0,max=1000,value=100)

        ),
    mainPanel(uiOutput('plot.ui'))
      )
    ),
  server=function(input,output){

    output$plot.ui=renderUI({
      plotOutput('plot',width=input$width,height=input$height)

    })
    output$plot=renderPlot({
      plot(runif(100000,1,100),runif(100000,1,100))
    })
  }
)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It's not shiny... just running `plot(runif(100000,1,100),runif(100000,1,100))` takes a second or two on my machine. That's a lot of points to plot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, so if you had fixed the problem in another way, let me know. What I attempted to to was adjust the size of plotOutput depending on what I was plotting (with certain inputs, I had horizontal bar plot with 1 bar or 10 bars.. needed to adjust the height accordingly.

Solution 1) Adjust the height of renderplot()
As explained by [jcheng5 here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/650). See if this solves the issue

Solution 2) Define a plot function, use isolate()

```
# Define a function that returns a plot
plot_function <- function(){
  plot(runif(100000,1,100),runif(100000,1,100)
}

# reactive UI and adjust the height here
output$plot.ui=renderUI({
   plotOutput("plot", height = -------------)
})
# call plot_function but use isolate()
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  isolate(plot_function())
}
```

This works for me. See if this solves the issue.